# PHP: merge two multi-dimensional arrays without merging depth

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have two arrays:

print_r($array_one):

```
Array 
( 
    [a] => Array ( 
        [param1] => 1 
        [param2] => 2 
    ) 
    [b] => Array ( 
        [param1] => 3 
        [param2] => 4 
    ) 
)
```

print_r($array_two):

```
Array
(
    [param3] => 5
)
```

I want to form an array that looks like:

```
Array
(
    Array 
    ( 
        [a] => Array ( 
            [param1] => 1 
            [param2] => 2 
        ) 
        [b] => Array ( 
            [param1] => 3 
            [param2] => 4 
        ) 
    ) 
    Array
    (
        [param3] => 5
    )   
)
```

But both array_merge() and array_merge_recursive() will create:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array ( 
        [param1] => 1 
        [param2] => 2 
    ) 
    [b] => Array ( 
        [param1] => 3 
        [param2] => 4 
    ) 
    [param3] => 5  
)
```

The original array was intended for a json encode to make a dimensional json file, but the result of merge of arrays is not what I want.

Would someone please point out how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just do something like:

```
$new_array = array();

$new_array[] = $array_one;
$new_array[] = $array_two;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like `$newArray = array($array1, $array2);` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this right, this is what you are looking for:

```
$output = array($array_one, $array_two);
```